# AJAX: How to load an internal webpage on initial load?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have my code for loading the pages into a Div. But how do I get it to load an internal page on the initial load. So when the website first loads it is not just a blank page. But "pages/index.php" will load inside the content area(apDiv2) instead of it being an empty blank page.

```
$('.menu_nav').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

       // I Assume that /loading.gif is the url to your gif file
    $('#apDiv2').empty().append($('<img src="img/loader1.GIF" />'));

    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: href,
        success: function(content)
        {
            $('#apDiv2').html (content);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: `<div id="#apDiv2"><?php include 'pages/index.php' ?></div>`

Comment: same way you do inside the click handler but why not do it as include at server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask for initial load .

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "pages/index.php",
    success: function(content)
    {
        $('#apDiv2').html (content);
    }
});
    });
```

Comment: THX this worked best for me on top of my previous code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`jQuery.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) event which is fired that the end of page loading.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //Page is loaded.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put HTML in your #apDiv2 and whatever is in there will be displayed on initial page load.

You would also have to remove the `empty()` (you don't want to empty the html if you want to show something) and add some css styles to loader1.gif so that it overlays on top of your content.

Comment: This doesn't answer how to get html into the element which is what was asked

Answer (score 0):

Don't overuse ajax, only use it when its needed!
In this specific case, its not needed, and to be honest, it would even be worse to use it than using plain server-side scripting (using ajax would require a request, which would make the total page load longer).
I would recommend to just include the file with php:

```
 <div id="#apDiv2"><?php include 'pages/index.php'; ?></div>
```

This will put the index.php code into the div, and it will be there when the page is loaded, without using any ajax.